# How to configure Hudson to archive empty folders

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, archive, artifacts

I have the following sample / test configuration that has Hudson create a directory of empty folders.  Its then instructed to archive everything within that folder, except it will not match empty folders and ends up archiving nothing.  Whats more annoying is that Hudson does not alert you that nothing matches the search string "root**", but when it builds, it says nothing matches the search string.

> [image]
>   <sub>(source: [86th.org](http://www.86th.org/hudson_artifacts.jpg))</sub>

We need Hudson to archive these empty folders for our installer since its expecting them.  I fear this may not be possible because of the text "Files to archive".

At any rate, How can I configure Hudson to archive empty folders as an artifact.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you what to see in result? (specific folders are created in specific place, a zip-archive of your project or anything else)

Comment: I want the artifacts to contain the empty folders that were created in the batch command above.  In our REAL project, the folders are necessary for our installer / deployment app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [Hudson source code](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Source+code), it seems as if artifact archiving is meant to only match against files.

You might want to [file a feature request](https://hudson.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectIssues) or [send an email to the USERS list](https://hudson.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectMailingListList), the Hudson team is pretty good about replying to requests and/or adding features in new releases.

Comment: sigh... Thanks Matt, I had hoped this wasn't the case but you're right

Comment: I think the better feature request would be a browser that lets you traverse the contents of a zip file artifact.

Comment: Thats not a bad idea Michael, it would help cut down on artifact size

Answer (score 3):

You should create the artifact that you want in your build scripts, and then have hudson archive that file.   So if you want a zip file that contains empty folders, do the appripriate zip command in your batch file or ant script.  Then archive the output file.

Comment: certainly a workable idea and i'll upvote it for that, but we prefer to have hudson zip up the files on demand via "Download these files as a zip".  That way we have the ability to browse the contents of the artifacts and download a single file or two if we choose to.

Answer (score 1):

I see three ways:

1. have your application NOT expect the folders but create them on demand.
2. or have the application create the folders at startup.
3. or you could just add dummy files in the folders :) just thinking out of the box.

Comment: +1 for placeholder (3.) workaround. Its easy and not so ugly at all. You need to do similar things for example when working with git.

Comment: yes definitely an option. I also like to set a readme.txt file there so any person can know that the folder is required to live.

Comment: #1 and #2 are not valid options when dirs need to exist for humans. #3 is a poor solution, and would probably be more confusing than helpful.